# Identifying trolls on this site

Tags: discussion

Is there a process for identifying *trolls* on this site. I suspect that we may have one, but am unclear as to policies/procedures

Comment: Moderators can take actions if they consider a user's actions to have gone too far. Until then though I don't think there's anything to be done besides vigorous flagging. if we're thinking of the same user, they've already been suspended on another site, so...

Comment: Is it me? What did I do this time?

Comment: @Yannis Totally haven't been writing enough.

Comment: @Yannis I don't think it's you, and it isn't the trollish-answerer from months ago, but one asking questions ... if I'm thinking of the same user.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't be so quick to brand a user a troll. Everyone's allowed to have a bad day.

That said, if someone's being rude or otherwise disruptive, use your flags. The site's moderators have access to all the data they need to fairly assess a user's actions, and all the tools they need to restrict those actions if they deem it necessary.

Comment: Well, **I** wasn't thinking of you! And the person I'm thinking of has a bad day **every** day. I won't swear they are a troll, they might just have terrible communication skills, but I have my suspicions.

Comment: Heh, I know you weren't thinking of me @TheHonRose, my comment was in jest. However, even if you are absolutely certain someone is being intentionally disruptive, calling them a troll won't help and it might even make things worse. Trolls love attention and thrive on antagonism. Don't feed them.

Comment: I actually think identifying trolls **is** important. Some people are just unpleasant, but trolls **deliberately** set out to disrupt a site. I entirely agree about "feeding" them,  I simply wanted to know if the site had a policy in place - most sites I'm on do.

Comment: She was talking about me! I want the troll hat!!

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Absolutely, Mark!  ;)

Comment: If there is a pattern of deliberately disruptive behavior, can we also use a custom flag on one of the user's posts to explain the situation?

Comment: @VixenPopuli Yes. If possible, add links to examples of the disruptive behaviour in your flag.

Answer (score 1):

I naddition to Yannis (if someone's being rude or otherwise disruptive, use your flags), add a comment as to why you consider something disruptive, rude or otherwise trollish.